# How to filter lines only if the filter is successful?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, external-command, filter

I have the following lines in `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim`:

```
" yapf integration
function FormatFile()
  :normal mp
  0,$!yapf
  :normal `p
endfunction
autocmd BufWritePre *.py call FormatFile()
```

Thus, whenever I save a `.py` file its contents are filtered through [yapf](https://github.com/google/yapf) and automatically consistently formatted. However, when there is a syntax error in my file yapf outputs a traceback instead of formatted code and my whole buffer gets replaced by that traceback. This is not desirable as other plugins would inform me about the error less intrusively.

I know that yapf exits with exit code 0 when it successfully outputs formatted code and exits with exit code 1 when it encounters a syntax error. Can I use that fact or any other trick to replace my buffer with the filter output ONLY when the filter is successful?

Comment: Quick and dirty solution... follow `:1,$!yapf` with `if v:shell_error | undo |  endif` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pieced together this workaround from lots of stackexchange posts and vim wiki content:

```
" yapf integration
function FormatFile()
  let buffer_content = join(getline(1, '$'), "\n")
  let filter_output = systemlist("yapf", buffer_content)
  if v:shell_error == 0
    let view = winsaveview()
    call deletebufline('.', 1, '$')
    call setline(1, filter_output)
    call winrestview(view)
  endif
endfunction
autocmd BufWritePre *.py call FormatFile()
```

Comment: you may want `winsaveview` and `winrestview` to handle the cursor positioning/etc.